# Event that runs on every request on C# web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need event that runs before or on every request made on server.

If that event exist I need to run some code on that event.

For example: Someone types http://www.website.com/some-link

I need to check this link before on before it's processed by application.

I am using C# web forms.

So far I am trying to find event in Global.asax.cs, something like

```
protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // need to track requested url
    // code that needs to be run with requested url.
}
```

Is there any proper solution for this situation?

Tnx

Comment: You need to use HttpModule.

Comment: Is this a url within your application? What are you checking for?

Comment: I need to check every url requested on server.
I need to compare requested url with some data in database for each request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the proper solution would be to use the event Application_BeginRequest, unless you want to complicate things and use httpmodules wich I wouldn't recommend.

```
protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    var host = Request.Url.Host;

    // your magic goes here
}
```

just as some information the order of all events is:

- Application_BeginRequest
- Application_AuthenticateRequest
- Application_AuthorizeRequest
- Application_ResolveRequestCache
- Application_AcquireRequestState
- Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute
- Application_PreSendRequestHeaders
- Application_PreSendRequestContent

  - asp.net page code is executed
- Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute
- Application_ReleaseRequestState
- Application_UpdateRequestCache
- Application_EndRequest

Comment: Is this the life cycle for only `webforms` or same as for the `mvc`? Asking just for the knowledge.. :)

Comment: mvc has a similar structure, but not as many events as web.forms , you can read some about it here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

Comment: Tnx for help, I also found this article http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

I will try to implement with Application_BeginRequest event.